# What is this distro?

Tags: distributions

[image]

What is this distro, I was just googling and there was this mysterious screenshot.

Comment: http://www.ehu.eus/AC/ABC.htm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An Ubuntu-base distro for Beowulf clusters developed by the University of the Basque Country in Spain: http://www.ehu.eus/AC/ABC.htm

> ABC GNU / Linux distribution is based on Ubuntu and specializes in the
>   automatic construction of high-performance Beowulf clusters with only
>   boot in "live " mode in frontend or being installed on your hard
>   drive. Diskless nodes tear through PXE. Use as Gnome window manager .
>   Integra Resource Monitor Ganglia . This is the first distribution that
>   integrates all these features. It was published a scientific article
>   on this system and presented at the IEEE Symposium ICAT2009 held in
>   Sarajevo (Bosnia & Herzegovina). Powered by Iker Castaños, Izaskun
>   Garrido Garrido and Aitor Automatic Control Group of the UPV / EHU
>   University of the Basque Country.

Translated from the [Spanish Wikipedia article](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABC_GNU/Linux).

Comment: What is a 'Berewolf cluster?'

Comment: Like werewolves, but they live on beer, not human flesh...

Comment: @Anonymous6 - Beware: theyre most ferocious when clustered.